# How to get Rails 7 to compile JSX files for React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, ruby-on-rails-7

Suppose I have a React model in javascript/application/components/star_rating.js.jsx and I want to do something like this somewhere else in my JS code:

```
    let starRating = <StarRating name={name} value={initialValue} onStarClick={onClick} />;
    ReactDOM.render(starRating, someContainerElem)
```

How am I supposed to do that now with Rails 7?

I've used both Rails and React in the past but never Rails 7. Apparently Rails 7 retired Webpack.

I used to use the react-rails gem if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Hi "Some Guy"**

[esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) handles that, see

- Tutorial 15mins [GoRails setup esBuild in Rails](https://gorails.com/episodes/esbuild-jsbundling-rails) with chris Olivers [Helper gem](https://github.com/excid3/esbuild-rails) (video, from 5:31 until 8:00)
- [jsbundling-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails)
- [Setting up Rails 7 for TypeScript and React](https://www.strictmode.io/articles/setting-up-rails-7-for-typescript-and-react)

its a middle way between the fat webpacker and the asset pipeline for its own. It "feeds" the standard asset pipeline: It builds, and that build is transferred by asset pipeline to the browser.

With that, javascript modules you are adding by `yarn add` instead of the standard [importmap-rails gem](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails). Packages then are managed by `package.json` like you know it from Webpacker.

On development and production machine `node` and `yarn` has to be installed and make sure that `yarn build` is running inside the app directory.

The development server you run by `./bin/dev` which is added by `jsbundling-rails` gem. This runs `yarn build --watch` in parallel to puma which refreshes the browser while developing, unlike hot module reloading like you know it from webpacker-dev-server, but super fast. In my case, with ruby mine, press cmd+S while coding and you see the changes immediately on the browser.

Follow the tutorials above and you should be good to go.